# How to set the colours of a terminal window depending on the running program?

Tags: terminal, theme

I'm just wondering how it would be possible to set a theme to my terminal windows according to the program/command I'm running in it.

In order to make it as clear as possible, here is an example :

---

I often use several terminal windows in order to manage programs or commands simultaneously, such as :

1. grep -Ril a pattern in a set of text files
2. watch ls in a specific directory
3. grep a pattern in a specific file
4. Launch a program
5. navigate

So would it be possible to assign a specific background colour for each terminal widow depending on that ?

In this example :

1. grep --> purple
2. ls --> brown
3. grep --> purple
4. program --> grey
5. navigate --> black

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell `alias` to both send the appropriate ANSI codes to the screen to change the color, and temporarily set the TERM variable to something that'll ensure that whatever you're running won't issue ANSI codes itself.

Or maybe run the command and pipe its output [through the appropriate stripper](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream).